# Wordpress 3.9.2 .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm new to wordpress (my version is 3.9.2) development, and in my wordpress site i have written htaccess file like this.

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^product_view/(.*)$ product_view/?section=Products&alias=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

</IfModule>`
```

So when some one clicks on my link

`http://mysite/product_view/data`

i want mysite to rewrite the url as

`http://mysite/product_view/?section=Products&alias=data`

It is not working please help me.
Best regards
Lanka

Comment: Try changing the order of your rule. Place your rule above the wordpress rules.

Comment: Are you sure it is 2.9.2 and not 3.9.2. If it is 2.9.2 then you are light years behind :-)